# Problems importing lib in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, fractions

I was looking for some library providing Fractions for Spark + Scala and found [this link](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math4/fraction/BigFraction.html) .

I am not sure, if I can use it or that's something unavailable for me?
In spark-shell I'm writing `import org.apache.commons.math4.fraction` and getting

```
<console>:23: error: object math4 is not a member of package org.apache.commons
       import org.apache.commons.math4.fraction
```

Though I can `import org.apache.commons` without any troubles.

Could you please explain me what's wrong? Or maybe you could recommend some other lib for Fractions?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download the `jar` file and use while running the `spark-shell`

Download the jar file from [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/download_math.cgi).

Now extract in some location

```
tar xvf <location of tar/ zip files>
```

Now start the `spark-shell` as

```
./spark-shell --jars path to this jar file commons-math3-3.6.1.jar
```

And use as

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.fraction
```